# Compare each element of a 2D array with the rest C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm new to C++, and what I have to do is to write a method that checks if a 2D array contains any duplicate items.

So for example, I have a `matrix[3][4]`, I've been able to compare the first element `[0][0]` with the rest, till the last one `[2][3]`.
The problem is that I don't know how to proceed, what I should do is that the method then compares the element `[0][1]` with the rest (except with the previous one and itself of course) and etc..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *I've been able to compare* - how? Where's the code that does that? Do you know what to do, and are just struggling with the implementation, or do you have no idea how to proceed with the algorithm itself?

Answer (score 0):

First of, the fact that it's a 2D array is irrelevant in this context; you want to find duplicates across the entire array, so you'd be better of with 1-dimensional indexing anyway. Coincidentally, that's a suggested way of handlings two-dimensional arrays in C++.

So assuming you *can* put the indices in some order, the general idea is to check every element with all *subsequent* elements. This will give you **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. A pseudocode is, unsurprisingly, two loops, and is a common pattern used e.g. for collision detection:

```
for (iterA = 0; iterA < num - 1; iterA++) {
    for (iterB = iterA + 1; iterB < num; iterB++) { // note how iterB starts one further
        if (*iterA == *iterB)
            return true; // found a duplicate
    }
}
```

In case of a 2D array, the `*iterA` dereference can be replaced with a function that breaks up the composite 1-dimensional index into two components, e.g. with `i % width, i / width`. This is, again, a very common pattern.

That being said, why bother? Make an `std::set`, start putting elements one-by-one and call `find` before every insert. If `find` returns something, break.

Comment: you don't even need to find, just inspect [the return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) of `insert`